# How to fix "Can not find module ".../template.config" error in React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to create a new application in React Native using `react-native init MyApp`  But I got this error:

```
√ Downloading template
× Copying template
error Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\Emre\AppData\Local\Temp\rncli-init-template-hNGjwo\node_modules\react-native\template.config'
```

What I've tried:

`npm install -g react-native-cli`

then

`react-native init MyApp`

What do I need to do to solve this problem?

Comment: does you solve the problem?

Comment: yes i solved it, try yarn global add @react-native-community/cli@2.0.0-rc.2 then react-native init MyApp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yarn global add @react-native-community/cli@2.0.0-rc.2` then `react-native init MyApp` worked for me

Comment: npm ERR! Could not install from "react-native-community\cli@2.0.0-rc.2" as it does not contain a package.json file.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `nvm`.
Fixed this issue by `nvm use 12.4.0`. Issue was using node `v10.16.3`:

[image]

Comment: I'm using 18.16.1 and still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have **npm** installed, you can do it with npm. Simply type:

*npm install -g @react-native-community/cli@2.0.0-rc.2*

*react-native init name_of_the_app*

This one worked just fine for me!