# Error while creating react-native cli project

Tags: react-native

Error:

> Error: Couldn't find the "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\rncli-init-template-oScLDz\node_modules\react-native\template.config.js file inside "react-native" template. Please make sure the template is valid. Read more: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/init.md#creating-custom-template

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I have tried with npm using and it worked.

```
npx react-native init YourAwesomeProject --npm
```

After that
I have uninstalled yarn completely. Because you can install libraries using npm. So I have removed the yarn using

```
npm uninstall -g yarn
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this worked but can you please explain how?
What is the difference between having this flag '--npm' and not having this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

- Remove the global react-native CLI: `npm uninstall -g react-native-cli` or `yarn global remove react-native-cli`
- And run again `npx react-native init YourAwesomeProject`

  or
- Run `npx react-native-cli init YourAwesomeProject`

Maybe these links can help:

https://github.com/react-native-community/cli#about

[How to fix "Can not find module ".../template.config" error in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58145014/how-to-fix-can-not-find-module-template-config-error-in-react-native)

Comment: I never saw this type of error before. Since the other alternatives didn't work, try to install the react native CLI globally: yarn global add react-native-cli or npm i -g react-native-cli and run react-native init AwesomeProject

Answer (score 0):

surely you have your root a file or folder .yarn/ package.json package-lock.json

Remove them and try again `rm -rf .yarn/ package.json .yarn/ package-lock.json`

Comment: I don't know why, but appending `--npm` fixed it. Never had to do that before.